# get multiple table with same columns data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, get

i have three table with same value of columns. example: say i have three table "**table1**", "**table2**", "**table3**" and each columns has "*id*", "*title*", "*description*", "*category*", "*date*", "*thumbnail*", "*admin*". now i'm trying to get all data from those **three** table. but there is a think, i want to check with ***if statement***. if *table1* not match with id, check *table2*. if table2 not match with id, check *table3* and at last show the data. please check my below code, i'm trying to get data from those three table:

```
<?php
            include('config/database.php');
            $id=$_GET['single'];
            $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from table1, table2, table3 where id='$id'  ");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $title=$row['title'];
            $date=$row['date'];
            $admin=$row['admin'];
            $thumbnail=$row['thumbnail'];
            $description=$row['description'];
            $category=$row['category'];
         }
          ?>
```

please help me to get all data from those three table with **if statement**
it will be better to understand if you post an answer. thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you want to display with **if statement** ?

Comment: i already solved my problem from a different method.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UNION` of 3 queries.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS tnum, * FROM table1 WHERE id = ?
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS tnum, * FROM table2 WHERE id = ?
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS tnum, * FROM table3 WHERE id = ?
    ) AS x
    ORDER BY tnum
    LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $id, $id, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row) {
    $title = $row['title']
    $date=$row['date'];
    $admin=$row['admin'];
    $thumbnail=$row['thumbnail'];
    $description=$row['description'];
    $category=$row['category'];
}
```

Adding the `tnum` column to the result orders them so the `table1` data is preferred, then `table2`, finally `table3`.

Comment: it's not working. can you please check your answer and edit it with my question code? thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments for how to enable error reporting for mysqli.

Comment: i don't found a good solution in your link. i'm new in web development. so please try to help me that i will understand easily.

Comment: I don't understand. Don't you see `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` in the first answer? That enables reporting of mysqli errors. Add that to your script and tell me what error you're getting when you try to run my query.

Comment: I'm sorry, I left out a step: `$result = $stmt->get_result();` Try the updated code.